# Docker much slower than regular server

Tags: python, docker, face-recognition, dlib

I'm running a python Flask server which is doing face recognition with https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.

The `face_encodings` function is taking 10 times longer when running through docker in comparison to just starting the server in my machine and I have no idea why.

I think the most important part of my Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-stretch

RUN cd ~ && \
    mkdir -p dlib && \
    git clone -b 'v19.9' --single-branch https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git dlib/ && \
    cd  dlib/ && \
    python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the docker container so much slower? Am I installing `dlib` in a wrong way?

Comment: Does the container have limited access to the CPU and Memory of the host machine?

Comment: Would that be a configuration in the `Dockerfile`? How do I know if it has that limitation? But even if that was the case, the code is using a single core, since I'm processing only one image.

Comment: The docker app (daemon) running on your machine has configuration options for how many resources docker is allowed to use.

Comment: CPUs is at 4, memory at 2GB and Swap at 1GB